# what is wrong with my DNS record (please help i'm desperated Part 02 )

Tags: subdomain, dns-zone, cpanel

[image: Latest DNS record]

After several modifications i did with the support of godaddy and some members in the forum here.
I got this [image: Latest DNS record]

Can someone here say to me why my domain is working (qubemarket.com ) but not my subdomain ?
I installed a Cname with the name trial because i want the subdomain to be the same as i have in my cpanel which is : trial.qubemarket.com

According to the forum recommendation i deleted the A record i had for the subdomain (anyway i couldn't name it trial, it was '' @'' ) refering on value @

So please, tell me what is wrong i really need your help, like really...

it's been 4 to 6 days i'm struggling with this simple thing and it's a big project.

Comment: The DNS record for trial.qubemarket.com appears to work fine. Nothing is wrong with it. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: hello, i have a, error saying DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when i type : 
www.trial.qubemarket.com

and when i type just trial.qubemarket.com i have ''too many redirect'' i guess it's because of ssl wordpress or conflict beetween SSL. 

can you say to me what you see on your side ? thank's for your help ...

Comment: You didn't add any record for  www.trial.qubemarket.com. And the redirects are from your web site, not your DNS.

Comment: what should the record of www.trial.qubemarket.com look like ? 
an A record and a Cname ? 
Please tell me in details

i really need your help i'm not experimented

Comment: It should be what you want it to be. Probably the same as trial.qubemarket.com.

Comment: okay i will do an A record with the name of www.trial and value of what ? @ or the ip adress of the main domain ?